# How do I use an HTML DOM Event on new tab load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a custom homepage which loads upon opening a new tab in Firefox.
I want to reposition the caret on load but I can't find the event which will handle this on a tab load.

The `window.onpageshow` and `window.onload` events do not work when the page is loaded from a new tab event, but work fine on a refresh or similar. 
Throwing the event in with an element has no effect either, such as:

```
<body onload="blah()">
```

Is there a way to call my cursor reposition function when the page loads in this manner? 
Edit: Here is the setCursor code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = ready;
function ready()
{
    setCursor(document.getElementById('sbar'), 0, 0)
};
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function setCursor(el, st, end) 
{
    if (el.setSelectionRange) {
        el.focus();
        el.setSelectionRange(st, end);
    } else {
        if (el.createTextRange) {
            range = el.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', st);
            range.select();
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no difference between window load and new tab load, for a web browser. If your insist on only load from you site, maybe something as HTTP header `referer` can help. But `referer` is on the server side, not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options if you want to hook the page load (tab load):

The first option is using `onload` event:

```
window.onload = ready;
function ready()
{
    alert("Hi !");
};
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vy79v39k/

The second option is placing your javascript at the very end of the body:

```
<body>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ready();
  </script>
</body>
```

The third option is using `jQuery` (**which I vote for!**) :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //Your code here
});
```

Or:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //Your code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I'm still having problems. The alert dialog works fine on a new tab, but my cursor relocation script still does not run on load. Interestingly, it works fine if I include an alert in the same onload function call - any idea whats going on? Code is at end of body, setCursor function wrapped in script tags. Did not get different results with jQuery. Thanks again! +1, but new member=noshow.

Comment: Could you please add the `setCursor` function code !